# NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: 'Storyboard doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'SomeController'

Tags: ios, ios5, storyboard, xcode4.2

While trying to test the `UIPageViewController`, which is new in iOS 5, I encountered the following problem:

> `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'SomeController'`

The thing is: `SomeController` is definitely part of the Project and attached to a View in the Storyboard.

I tried to re-attach it, clean the project, restart everything and so on. Doesn't work.

This seems to be an exotic error because I didn't get even a single hit while googling for it.
Does anyone know what could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

I just found out, that the problem was that i didn't give the Scene, which was connected to "SomeController" the Identifier "SomeController".
I assumed connecting the class to the scene would be enough

Comment: Now, I have exactly same problem. But I cannot understand 'give the scene to SomeCOntroller'. What does this mean?

Comment: Somewhere in your code, (for example in the prepareForSegue method) you specify an identifier for a viewController. You have to make sure, that the Controller you want to reach with this, actually has this Identifier in your storyboard. To do this, open you storyboard, klick on the viewController and in the utilities (right-hand part of the screen) open the Attributes Inspector (Symbol that looks like an arrow pointed downwards). There you can specify an Identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Its in the Identity Inspector you set the "StoryBoard ID" to be "SomeController" not the Attributes Inspector, otherwise you are right user1041920.